# What is the command to check Fortify version and Fortify rules pack version?

Tags: fortify

I'm new to Fortify.
I need to add Fortify version and Fortify rules pack version to PDF Fortify report?

I need to add that command to template , such that while running reportGenerator it will pick dynamically the version number and update the PDF, Instead of harcoding the Fortify version.

Could you please let us know the command to check the Fortify version and rules pack version (Not from GUI, through console mode or command line)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For SCA:

sourceanalyzer -version

For checking the rulepacks, either run fortifyupdate or:

cd /Core/config/rules/
head -n11 *.bin

Answer (score 1):

grep -n -binary  Version= FORTIFY_INSTALL_ROOT/Core/config/rules/*.bin

this will produce output looks like
FORTIFY_INSTALL_ROOT/Core/config/rules/core_abap.bin:3:40:Version=2014.4.0.0008

and 2014.4.0.0008 is the rulpack version.

Answer (score 0):

HP SCA version:

> sourcenanalyzer -v
>
> Fortify Static Code Analyzer 5.13.0.0065